# Zendesk custom fields not showing on ask for detail section in chat bot

Tags: chatbot, zendesk

I am creating a chatbot on Zendesk and facing issues regarding getting user detail fields in **ask for detail**  section in the .
[image]

Fields will show something like this to end users I am trying to add more fields for this but you can see in the above screenshot there is no option to add.
[image]

Please let me know, if Can we add fields or not I tried adding custom fields in tickets & objects but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the permission for the the custom ticket field to: **Customer can edit**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No i did not for what purpose is this?

Comment: The purpose is to allow end users to set this field. If you do not set the permission it will be not shown in the bot flow.